# Handling forms in React using Context API

Tags: reactjs, forms, react-context

In my e-commerce project in admin panel there'are forms used to edit information about categories, products, users etc.
I'm using Context API for my global state.
So in my `CategoryEdit` component I'm using

```
<Consumer>
  {value => {
    const { categories, dispatch } = value;
    if (categories === undefined || categories.length === 0) {
      return <Spinner />;
    } else {
      const category = categories.filter(category => {
        if (this.props.match.params.id !== undefined) {
          return category.id == this.props.match.params.id;
        } else {
          return category;
        }
      });
      return category.map(category => {
        return (
          <React.Fragment key={category.id}>
            <h1 className="title">Edit category</h1>
            <form className="form" onSubmit={this.saveChanges.bind(this, dispatch)}>
              <input type="hidden" value={category.id} name="cat_id" onChange={this.handleChange} />
              <label htmlFor="cat_name" className="form__label">
                Category name
              </label>
              <br />
              <input type="text" className="form__input-field" name="cat_name" value={category.name} onChange={this.handleChange} />
              <br />
              <label htmlFor="cat_title" className="form__label">
                Category title
              </label>
              <br />
              <input type="text" className="form__input-field" name="cat_title" value={category.title} onChange={this.handleChange} />
              <br />
              <label htmlFor="cat_description" className="form__label">
                Category discription
              </label>
              <br />
              <textarea className="form__input-field" name="cat_description" value={category.description} onChange={this.handleChange} />
              <br />
              <button type="submit" className="admin__button admin__button-success">
                Save
              </button>
              <button type="button" className="admin__button admin__button-secondary">
                Cancel
              </button>
            </form>
            {this.state.isSaved && <div>Changes saves</div>}
          </React.Fragment>
        );
      });
    }
  }}
</Consumer>
```

to give fields initial values fetched from database.
But then when I'm trying to change values in field using common

```
handleChange = e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  this.setState({
    [e.target.name]: e.target.value
  });
}
```

Obviously, nothing happens, because values are not bound from the `CategoryEdit` component `state`.
Also putting `setState()` to `componentDidMount()` doesn't work, because data in `Provider` is fetched in async way, so at first `value` is empty.
I do not want to bind this form value changes to global state, because this changes can be canceled and they should be refetched after submitting form.
So what I want is 
- to initially fill form using values from `Provider`, 
- then pass them to `CategoryEdit` state once, 
- then handle changes of the component state,
- submit data to database using asyncronous `fetch()` inside `CategoryEdit` component
- tell `Provider` via `action` that it can update

Is this the right pattern to do such things, or there's a better way to handle forms in React using Context.

Comment: Yes this is the right way to do this. Make sure you fill the local state of `CategoryEdit` with the data from your context. Then fill the input fields in the form using the local state NOT context.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I got it solved.
I've changed component from class component to functional component and worked the whole thing using `React Hooks`.

If anyone interested - leave a comment, and I'll paste the whole component code.

Comment: Sure please do :).